# Получить из API лишь часть данных, а не всё сразу

Tags: django, api, requests, django-rest-framework

API возвращает данные в формате `[{"url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/position/1/","title":"Python developer","active":true,"time_create":"2022-03-17"},{"url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/position/2/","title":"C++ developer","active":false,"time_create":"2022-03-17"}]`
То есть это список состоящий из словарей. API написано на DRF. Запросы к API я отправляю через библиотеку requests. Как мне получить из ответа не все поля, а лишь title. Чтобы ответ был в стиле `[Python developer, C++ developer]` Можно ли сделать это, не используя циклы и не изменяя бэкенд часть? Может библиотека requests умеет что-то подобное?

Answer (score 0):

> не используя циклы и не изменяя бэкенд часть?

нет

```
ans = [el["title"] for el in response]
```